# Edited answer converted to a comment produces "no edit history found for this comment" message

Tags: bug, edits, moderator-tools, convert-to-comment

When an edited answer is converted into a comment, the comment will get the familiar pencil icon to indicate it has been edited, but if you click on it (an option only available to ♦ moderators), it says "no edit history found for this comment":

[image]

Either the pencil should not be shown, or the post edit history should be migrated to the comment as well.