# Icon about comment edits is shown, even though this comment has no edits

Tags: bug, comments, moderator-tools, tooltips, comment-edits

For example, in [this](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/238339/15479) question.

> [image]

But if you click on this icon, the message about no edits is shown.

> [image]

P.S. this comment was created by moving an answer into a comments by moderator.

Comment: @ShadowWizardisEarForYou tooltip on this icon says "This comments was changed 1 time", and by clicking there is no history of editing. It's not the best UX experience.

Comment: As a side note, being able to click on the pencil icon and see edit history is a moderator-only ability as far as I know.

Comment: I already reported this bug here: [Edited answer converted to a comment produces "no edit history found for this comment" message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/330714/edited-answer-converted-to-a-comment-produces-no-edit-history-found-for-this-co) Also, the message doesn't seem to be translated :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is proper attribution given when a moderator edits someone's comment?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248537/is-proper-attribution-given-when-a-moderator-edits-someones-comment) is an additional (earlier reported) related issue (if the Pencil *tool-tipped* that the *edit* was the result of a conversion then having a Pencil would be accurate) to Glorfindel's duplicate:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/330714/282094